# Requiring files from the root directory

Tags: php, require

Is it possible to require files (using php require) from the directory where my website is placed?
For example, my website is in the directory mywebsite which is in the root directory. There is another directory there. Can I require files from this another directory?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can require files from anywhere that has the appropriate permissions.

This requires the file from the current directory (NOT always where the current PHP script is, so be careful of that):

```
require("whatever.php");
```

This will require `whatever.php` from `somefolder` which is in the current directory.

```
require("somefolder/whatever.php");
```

Finally, you can give an absolute path like this:

```
require("/var/www/includes/whatever.php");
```

Require from parent directory:

```
require("../includes/watherver.php");
```

It doesn't matter really where you get it from, provided you have the permissions set correctly, and PHP is configured in such a way to allow you to do so.

Comment: I think I got misunderstood. Here's the structure of the root directory.
/include
/mywebsite

All the files for my website are in the mywebsite directory. Can I require files from the include directory?

Comment: Absolutely, just use `../` to indicate "parent" directory.  See my last edit.

Comment: The `open_basedir` setting might give you some problems, but that's about it really.

Comment: No, no, no. Let's do it this way. I've got a website www.site.provider.com and I've got a domain mywebsite When I type in www.mywebsite.com I go to www.site.provider.com/mywebsite/index.php My question is whether I can require files from www.site.provider.com/include?

Comment: @user355366, I just gave you the answer... use the parent directory.  If this isn't want you want, put it into terms of where your files are located on the server.  Where it appears on the web isn't of concern here.  (Including files over HTTP is a very **bad** idea.)

Comment: I'll put it this way.
If I want to access my home page I can get there in two ways:
www.site.provider.com/mywebsite/index.php
or
www.mywebsite.com

When I access my home page the first way I can access any directory I want, but when I get there the other way, I can only access directories in 'mywebsite'. Do you know what I mean now?

Comment: @user355366, web paths have nothing to do with where those files actually on the server, which is what matters here.  No matter how you access your website, assuming those files are located in the same physical place in the filesystem, then your includes will work the same.  You can also use relative paths, making this a non-issue completely.  If you still don't understand this, then show us your `require()` lines, as well as a directory listing of your website.

Comment: Here's the file test.php which looks like this `require("../0include/file.php");`
`echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

The file file.php looks like this echo('hello');

If I put www.mywebsite/test.php in the browser I get this:
Warning: require(../0include/test.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /file.php on line 8
/
/test.php
If I put www.site.server.com/mywebsite/test.php I get this:
hello/
/mywebsite/TEST.PHP

Answer (score 1):

I have been using

`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myfile.php';`

Answer (score 0):

It should be no problem to require from an arbitrary existing and readable directory.

Image you have:

/

--folder1

--folder2

and in folder1 is your index.php and in folder2 is your to_require.php

Then you could write:

```
require('../folder2/to_require.php')
```

That's because you can go up in your directory tree with **..**

Comment: No, no, no.
Let's do it this way.
I've got a website www.site.provider.com
and I've got a domain mywebsite
When I type in www.mywebsite.com I go to www.site.provider.com/mywebsite/index.php
My question is whether I can require files from www.site.provider.com/include?